# How to get back the "Login Window..." icon in the menu bar?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, screen-lock

Once I've upgraded to Lion I had a new icon on my Menu Bar next to Spotlight. It was an outline of a mugshot similar like one of the Guest account.

When I clicked on that icon I was able to select "Login Window..." which basically locked my Mac.

For some reason this icon is gone. I don't use it frequently so I can't clearly say when it went missing but I'd say within last 10 days probably.

How do I get it back? I have no idea where to re-enable it.

Comment: The personal silhouette icon is the Fast User Switching menu. I have an entry called "Login Screen" below the user choices. Is that what you are missing?

Comment: Thanks @Nate Bird. Only just found it and answered it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be enabled via **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups** > [Unlock] > **Login Options** > **Show fast user switching menu as...**

[image]